# Creating a new tab using do.call in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, do.call

I have a Shiny app where the underlying data powering the visualization may have different numbers of variables. So in order to plot correctly, I used `do.call` to feed the list of ggplots into the UI as follows:

```
#do.call will call the navbarPage function with the arguments in the tabs list
shinyUI(fluidRow(
  column(12,
         "", 
         do.call(navbarPage,tabs)
  )
)
)
```

Which gives me what I expect:

[image]

This works spectacularly. My question is, I would like to add another tab. This would be a 'static' tab, that is always present regardless of how many ggplots the underlying data may have. It will be a tab that has some text instructions on how to use the app.

I'm envisioning another tab on the far left, saying 'Instructions'.

I attempted solutions along these lines:

```
   shinyUI(fluidRow(
      column(12,
             "", 
             do.call(navbarPage,tabs),
             navbarPage(verbatimTextOutput("does something like this work?"))
      )
    )
```

...with no luck.

As I tried to solve this, I realized my problem could be rephrased as, 'How do I include an extra argument to a `do.call` function?

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Naive question: you can't extend `tabs` to include the "static" tab?

Comment: It might be the only solution... :/